Implementing Soft Delete for Bulk Actions / Empty Trash
I successfully introduced the concept of soft deletion for a custom post type by implementing an additional post_status named deleted. Whenever I click on a «Delete permanentely» link in the list, the post gets this new status and is kept in the database.
Current solution
The following code parts (concept taken from here) are working fine as long as I delete only one post at a time:
add_action( 'init', 'registerDeletedPostStatus' );
add_action( 'before_delete_post', 'softDelete' );

function registerDeletedPostStatus() {
    $args = [ 
        // ...
    ];
    register_post_status( 'deleted', $args );
}

function softDelete( $postId ) {
    if ( get_post_type( $postId ) != 'MY_POST_TYPE' ) {
        return;
    }

    // change post status to "deleted"
    wp_update_post( [
        'ID'          => $postId,
        'post_status' => 'deleted'
    ] );

    // return back to list of trashed but not yet deleted posts
    wp_redirect( add_query_arg( [
        'post_type'   => 'MY_POST_TYPE',
        'post_status' => 'trash'
    ], admin_url( 'edit.php' ) ) );

    exit;
}

The problem

When clicking on the «Empty Trash» button, only the first post gets the new status. The others are kept in the trash. I know this is because of wp_redirect()-call after the first post has been changed.
The same happens when selecting multiple post and choosing "Delete permanentely" in the bulk actions dropdown.
If I remove wp_redirect(), the posts are permanentely erased as this is the standard behaviour. I would like to prevent this.

How can I implement soft deletion when a) emptying the trash, and b) for multiple posts?

For this I suggest you to use given solution which ensure each post is processed individually without interrupting the batch processing, and also allowing soft deletion to work for both emptying the trash and bulk actions.
You need to update the softDelete function with the given code.
function softDelete( $postId ) {
    if ( get_post_type( $postId ) != 'MY_POST_TYPE' ) {
        return;
    }

    // Here we are changing post status to "deleted".
    wp_update_post( [
        'ID'          => $postId,
        'post_status' => 'deleted'
    ] );

    // Here we are stopping further actions.
    remove_action( 'before_delete_post', 'softDelete' );
}

Also we need to add given piece of code which will handles bulk actions and empty the trash by updating the post status to deleted for each post and preventing further deletion.
add_action( 'wp_trash_post', 'soft_delete_for_bulk_and_empty_trash' );

function soft_delete_for_bulk_and_empty_trash( $postId ) {
    if ( get_post_type( $postId ) != 'MY_POST_TYPE' ) {
        return;
    }

    // Here we are changing post status to "deleted".
    wp_update_post( [
        'ID'          => $postId,
        'post_status' => 'deleted'
    ] );

    // Here we are preventing permanent deletion.
    add_filter( 'pre_trash_post', '__return_true' );
}

This should works for you.
